# Is it worth it to make a local variable static to prevent constant re-creation?

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization

Suppose I have a function in C/C++ which is called quite frequently (let's say it's connect to a timer which is timeout at least 10 times per second) and that function needs to use a given variable/container (an integer or maybe a string or an array). Now, naturally enough, the process of creating this variable in memory costs some processor clocks; running the same function again and again therefore means I'll loose quite some "processor clock ticks" for doing exactly the same thing many times. This could be prevented by either making that variable global, member of the function's class or `static`: in any of such cases, the variable/container would be created only once and many "processor clock ticks" used to always do the same operation would be saved.

My question is: is this operation actually worth it (when it comes to performance)? In other words, is the creation of variables as global, members of a class or as `static` an actual way to improve (even if just a little bit) the performance of a code or is there something else that might easily kill any possible improvement? (For example, `static` variables might be always created on the heap instead of in the stack, and since the first is slower then the second, this would end up killing the performance of such strategy) Or there is no "global rule" for knowing things because it depends a lot of specific issues such as the processor being used, optimizations done by the compiler and types of variables/containers such that only a benchmark with case-by-case study could actually tell the difference?

Comment: _"is this operation actually worth it when it comes to performance"_ - Did profiling your code indicate a performance issue with using non-static locals?

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: Note that static/global makes the function non-reentrant and thread-unsafe.

Comment: With performance and optimization, the general rule is "don't fix it if it ain't broke."  You have to have a measurable problem (usually determined with a profiler).  What you are describing is something that might or might not lead to a measurable performance problem; however the fixes you mention could lead to other problems.

Comment: It would really depend on how you use that variable. If it is a constant, I would say that yes, it is definitely worth it (I know that a static variable in C/C++ (pre c++11) needs to be constant).

Comment: I belive it mostly depends on code, yet I think compiler can predict that big const object inside function will be reused. Knowing this, it would store it somewhere

Comment: Are you asking about C, or C++?  If you have a local variable, or a local variable of "POD" type in C++, the cost of creating it on the stack is near 0.

Comment: Creating an object 10 times per second isn't "quite frequently". Millions of times per second is.

Comment: @Snappawapa I'm not sure where you got that from, but it's definitely not true. Static variables (both in a function and in a class) don't need to be constant in pre-C++11.

Comment: @celticminstrel I came across it a few days ago using g++, it wouldn't let me compile without making it so, saying that it needed to be in pre-c++11

Comment: @Snappawapa You're probably misunderstanding the error message? For example, class static variables often need to be declared outside the class, unless they are initialized to a constant integral value. C++11 relaxed these rules.

Comment: @celticminstrel that might have actually been it, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use local variables. Only if you cannot…
2. Use object variables. Only if you cannot…
3. Use global (or static) variables.
4. Avoid point 3.

Comment: This depends on the code's application.  A life critical application  may favor no re-entrant code and lots of global objects as dynamic allocation and unknown maximum stack depth are dangerous. This 1,2,3 list is good for _many_ apps, not all.

Comment: People able to work on life critical applications don't need this list. ;-)

Comment: Yet folks who will work in the future on such devises may look at this list.  Something to think about when we are in the old-coders home.

Comment: You are right, of course. And I really appreciate your note. When it comes to life there is only a single rule: **no failure**.